# Probability of Intersection of any set (Union Bound Question)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For any set $$A_k,1 <= k <=n$$ we have

[can we prove]

$$P(\bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_k) >= \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k) - (n-1)  $$

Comment: What do you mean by the product of sets $\prod_k A_k$? The title mentions intersection and union but that is (more commonly) denoted by $\cap_k A_k$ and $\cup_k A_k$ respectively. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For any collection of events, $\ \left\{B_k\right\}_{k=1}^n\ $,
$$
P\left(\bigcup_\limits{k=1}^nB_k\right)\ge \sum_\limits{k=1}^nP\left(B_k\right)\ .
$$
Put $\ B_k = \Omega\setminus A_k\ $ and use the identities $\ \bigcup_\limits{k=1}^nB_k= \Omega\setminus\bigcap_\limits{k=1}^nA_k\ $, and  $\ P\big(\Omega\setminus E\big)=1-P(E)\ $ for any event $\ E\ $.